# Issue with the Nested Queries

Tags: mysql, sqlite

Hey guys I have been working on this but I am not able solve it. Can any one help me with this please? I tried many ways but couldn't solve it, can anyone help me by using nested queries and just using (GROUP BY, HAVING, SELECT,FROM and WHERE)

> (Qs)You would like to know the departments with more than 5 full-time
>   young employees (Age <25) each department has. Calculate the average
>   salary of the employees who work for those departments. This newly
>   calculated field should be named as "AvgSalary" and be returned by
>   your query.

Here is the SCHEMA of this.

```
Employee(EmployeeID: Integer, EmpName: String, Age: Integer, Salary: Real)  
Department(DeptID: Integer, DeptName: String, Budget: Real, ManagerID: Integer)
Works(EmployeeID: Integer, DeptID: Integer, Percent_Time: Integer)
```

Comment: Average salary for all employees, or just those under 25?

Comment: No nesting is required for that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only interested in the average salary of the target group (the under 25s), then no nesting is required...

```
SELECT d.*
     , AVG(********) AvgSalary 
  FROM ******** 
  JOIN ********
    ON ******** = ******** 
  JOIN ********  
    ON ******** = ******** 
 WHERE ******** = 100 
   AND ******** < 25 
 GROUP 
    BY ******** 
HAVING COUNT(*) > 5;
```

If you need the average salary of ALL employees within departments returned by the target group, then you *can* use a subquery, but I would use a CASE statement,